# How to choose the levels order of the fill variable with waffle::geom_waffle()

Tags: r, ggplot2, waffle

I don't understand how I can change the levels order of the fill variable in R waffle::geom_waffle().

It seems that sorting the variable is ineffective since it's always sorted by the number of observations.

```
# First example
db_graph <- data.table::data.table(group = c("A", "B"),
                                   n     = c(13, 25))

ggplot2::ggplot(data    = db_graph,
                mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill   = group,
                                       values = n)) +
  waffle::geom_waffle(flip = TRUE)

# Second example
db_graph <- db_graph[j = group := forcats::fct_rev(group)]

ggplot2::ggplot(data    = db_graph,
                mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill   = group,
                                       values = n)) +
  waffle::geom_waffle(flip = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by reordering your dataframe using e.g. `setorder(db_graph, group)`. But you are right. I would have expected too that the order is determined by the order of the factor levels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(waffle)
library(forcats)

db_graph <- data.table::data.table(
  group = c("A", "B"),
  n = c(13, 25)
)

db_graph <- db_graph[j = group := fct_rev(group)]

ggplot(
  data = db_graph,
  mapping = aes(
    fill = group,
    values = n
  )
) +
  geom_waffle(flip = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
setorder(db_graph, group)

ggplot(
  data = db_graph,
  mapping = aes(
    fill = group,
    values = n
  )
) +
  geom_waffle(flip = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Staying with the tidyverse, you can use arrange().

```
db_graph <- tibble(
  group = c("A", "B"),
  n = c(13, 25)
)

db_graph %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = group,
           values = n)) +
  geom_waffle(flip = TRUE)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).